# What D3 modules have I used?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, module, dependencies

Is there a way to see which development dependencies you've used in a D3 project **after** building it, rather than bundling them beforehand?

I'm making a visualization right now using the entire D3V4 package, not just individual modules. I'm not sure which ones I've used and the project is quite long, so it would be useful to see what I've used after building out my project.

Comment: I don't see how this could be done the smart way. Which leaves us with the hard way: remove the full package and add the individual modules one by one until your project builds successfully. Since D3 comprises a total of 30 modules this won't take that much work and you can take some shortcuts adding the most obvious choices at once.

Comment: I second @altocumulus here. Besides that, depending on how many modules your code use (probably a lot), using the full package or the micro libraries may not make any difference.